# Are all istreams skipping white space like `cin`?

Tags: c++, input, format

As far as I know `std::cin` skips all white spaces, is this the case with all the other `std::istream`: `std::fstream`, `std::sstream`, `std::iostream` objects, do they skip white space? For example, if you want to read from file containing white space separated values, do you need to specify skipping in the same order you specify any other input format structure?

Example, if you read values in the format *(val1, val2)*:

```
char par1, comma, par2;
double x,y;
is >> par1 >> x >> comma >> y >> par2;
// check if any input
if(!is) return is;
// check for valid input format
if (par1 != '(' || comma != ',' || par2 != ')')
```

For white space separated values, do you need to specify  *white space* as format marker?

```
int val1;
char whSp= ' '; // or string whSp = " "; 
is >> val1 >> whSp;
```

Comment: `cin` is an object, it doesn't "do" anything. Formatted extraction operations are operations, and they *do* things (like skipping whitespace).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default yes, although this behavior is governed by the base class `std::ios_base`. When the stream initializes its buffer by calling `init`, it will also set the `skipws` flag (among other things); this flag is used by formatted input functions (such as `operator>>`) to determine whether to skip whitespace or not. Unless this flag is later modified directly or through a manipulator, formatted functions will always skip whitespace.

[image]

As to which characters are considered whitespace this depends on the `ctype` facet of the locale that is imbued in the stream at the time the function is called, for the default C locale (and indeed most locales) these are \t, \n, \v, \f, \r and space.

Answer (score 2):

> As far as I know cin skips all white spaces, is this the case with all the rest: fstream, sstream, iostream, do they skip white space?

The behavior of all standard stream types (with regards to white space), is the same (otherwise they would break the Liskov Substitution principle).

> For example, if you want to read from file containing white space separated values, do you need to specify skipping in the same order you specify any other input format structure?

That's a correct way to do it. You can also use [peek](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/peek) and [ignore](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) to skip characters.

> For white space separated values, do you need to specify white space as format marker?

The example you give here is not correct.

Either way, to control the space controlling policy, have a look at [std::skipws and std::noskipws](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws) stream manipulators.

Comment: So by default: `int val1;
 is >> val1;`